# Why XmlInputFormat is not provided by hadoop?

Tags: xml, hadoop, mahout

I am working with hadoop map-reduce. I have to process the data from `.xml` file, parse it and store the output into the database.

While working on this when I need to pass my xml to mapper, I found that the `XmlInputFormat.class` is not provided by hadoop by default and we have to use **mahout's [XmlInputFormat](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/ad84344e4055b1e6adff5779339a33fa29e1265d/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/classifier/bayes/XmlInputFormat.java)** for it.

I wonder when Xml is being use vastly, why hadoop haven't provided the `XmlInputFormat` for this rather than explicitly creating custom XmlInputFormat bye extending `TextInputFormat` for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well even though xml is vastly used, providing framework with special features towards a technology, might not be a good idea. It may be like an endorsement. At high level, Mapreduce is designed to accept different formats. Infact these days json is being used vastly due to its size features compared to xml. Even I had the similar issue.

But its up to the user to decide the input of map reduce and can use, different parsers(Jackson or gson for json and JAXB for xml) if they are in a single line or like above using RecordReader implementation

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input. But as for JSON there is also provision in java so I was curious for mapreduce as most of the time data will be in json or xml format. But the description you have given is pretty much assuring.

Comment: Ya, json and xml are standalone, and the languages like python and java need provision to interact with them, So we have Jackson and jaxb for json and xml respectively. So a framework like hadoop gave the same option to handle them using RecordReader concept. Hope I helped you in this aspect. Happy Learning